# Show Embedded Video based on Form Input

Tags: jquery, html

I am looking to design a client portal, in which the client is provided with a six digit code. This code is the last 6 digits of a Vimeo URL.

EG:

www.vimeo.com/XXXXXX

I need the client to enter the 6 digits on the site and for the embedded player to show the specific video.

I have copied the embed code from Vimeo, and need the field "text" to be added to the code where shown

```html
<form action="iframe.php" target="my-iframe" method="post"> 
    <label for="text">Some text:</label>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
    <input type="submit" value="post">
</form>
<iframe name="my-iframe" iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/THIS_IS_WHERE_THE_FORM_ENTRY_SHOULD_BE_ON_SUBMIT" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code as input value-> **356273024**

**Html CODE**

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
<input type="button" class='btn' value="post">
```

**JQUERY CODE**

```
$('body').on('click','.btn',function(){
$('iframe').attr('src',"https://player.vimeo.com/video/"+$('#text').val());
});
```